# Angular.js Error: matrix not invertible

Tags: angularjs, three.js

I am using AngularJS with ThreeJS, trying to make some 3D interactive graphics in my web app.The ThreeJS part successfully shows up and works as expected but AngularJS seems to be not working. 
In my index.html, I have:

```
<html ng-app="plantApp">
    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <plant-canvas></plant-canvas>
        <div>{{data}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here plant-canvas is a custom directive and its definition is:

```
angular.module("plantApp")
.directive("plantCanvas", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: 'partials/canvas.html',
        controller: 'canvasCtrl',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        }
    };
});
```

canvasCtrl is a controller only for canvas manipulation and canvas.html is the partial html file for canvas stuff. I am now trying to display a variable called test and the graphics. So in the partial html file, I have

```
<div>{{test}}</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Where the container is used by ThreeJS for drawing. In canvasCtrl, I have:

```
angular.module("plantApp")
.controller("canvasCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.test = "This is a test";

  //ThreeJS code for drawing here

});
```

All the functions for graphics are also in canvasCtrl. When I run the website, I have

```
{{test}}
```

showing up, followed by the graphics part. I have no clue how to solve this since the error seems to be generated by three.js but caught by AngularJS as well. Angular does not manipulate graphics directly but the script is written in the controller. If I move "" to index.html and move the graphics part of code to index.html within a script tag, then AngularJS will work fine - "This is a test" will show up. What should I do? Is there a better way to mix ThreeJs with AngularJS?

I think a way to solve this problem is to let angular ignore this error and continues its work, is it possible to do this?

Comment: What does the "matrix not invertible" mentioned in your title have to do with this?

Comment: It's the error I have in console. It does exist because of three.js but was caught by Angular when I put the code in my controller. I am pretty sure this error is preventing Angular from working. As I said, after moving the graphics part of script into index.html, angular will not give me this error.

Comment: Please show the code of the controllers?

Comment: Both; feel free to make cuts on parts you are sure are irrelevant

Comment: I see you have several elements with id "container" in the page: can you remove one and see what happens?

Comment: I removed it, it is still the same....

Comment: I wrapped up the graphics part of code with try{}catch(err){}. It ignores the error and everything works now.